# How might a higher-dimensional observer "see" a nuclear fission reaction in our universe?

Tags: science-fiction

In the Bulk-brane cosmological model, what might an observer in the Bulk  "see" of a nuclear fission reaction in our brane?
Or indeed what might the observable effect be of any major energy "event" in our brane, Such as a Supernova.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675400/what-is-bulk-in-brane-cosmology

> The bulk is the higher-dimensional space in which our brane lives. It
> need not be a brane, although it could be.
>
> As an example, in the Randall-Sundrum model, our observable Universe
> is a brane living at one end of a warped-throat geometry. The word
> "bulk" describes the full spacetime.
>
> It's also useful to think of an analogy to condensed matter physics.
> Let's say you have some chunk of material, with paint on one surface.
> The painted surface is like the brane, and the "chunk" or "bulk" of
> the material is, well, like the bulk.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. What is the worlbuilding problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like a cosmology question. Please read our [help] to understand our scope

Comment: Hello new user. Please make your question self-contained. I do not know what is this Bulk-brane model of which you speak. Include enough detail to answer the question.

Comment: This is a really cool question! (Bain, as the second comment says, it would be helpful to include a bit more explanation of the context behind the question.) I hope to make an answer later today.

Answer (score 6):

**Probably Nothing**

I think you are talking about our universe being a 3-dimensional sheet (membrane) in a higher-dimensional space (Bulk). Usually when we talk about this we imagine light and particles and tables and chairs and stuff being bound to the sheet so they don't escape from the universe. That means the supernova shoots all its stuff inside the membrane. Nothing escapes into the bulk. There is nothing for the higher-dimensional observer to see.

For a lower-dimensional analogue suppose the supernova is on a table, and it shoots light in all directions along the surface of the table. Since no light goes upwards to your eyes, you cannot see the star at all.

Some people say gravity is "so weak" because it extends into the bulk. I don't know the maths behind this. But there is enough lore there to say the observer can sense the gravity inside the brane. They could observe something that generates a lot of gravitational flux. Like two black holes colliding.

Comment: Wouldn't their be "ghost" gravity affecting the matter in our brane from other branes?  Or is that a potential alternate to dark matter?

Comment: Thanks for he answer Daron!! That makes sense. Yes I was thinking (because of the idea that gravitons are closed string, according to the Bulk-Brane theory,) that there may be some sort of gravitational sense as you say, or some way that the higher dimensional being could see stuff that goes on in our 4-dim brane..mmm...I need to think a it more...And also, couldn't quantum level events not leave behind a mark in the Bulk? (I'm not being scientific here I know!!)

Comment: So the scenario in my story is that some large energy event happens in the real world, but there is a higher-dimensional being that is alerted to that event....and comes back to wreak revenge etc etc...so really, I'm just looking for a way to describe this that sounds feasible....

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Don't you just love questions that are their own answer?

Comment: @Michael Richardson. No as far as I understand other branes (universes) cannot interact with other branes directly. Although there is a theory that the Bulk itself is a brane itself, so in that case, yes....I guess!

Comment: There are two phenomena you have to consider. The first is an emission event, and the other is space curvature. Things like supernova are emissions, and we can determine how many dimensions they emit into by measuring their distance drop-off. The square of the distance tells us that they only expand into three dimensions. This is just accounting. Space-time curvature doesn't have that limitation. Objects that curve space (i.e., have gravity) also drop off at the square of the distance, but there's nothing that prevents the curvature from also happening elsewhere.

Comment: @RobertRapplean - Sorry Robert you're going to have to run that one passed me again! You obviously have the scientific background that I do not. If you could keep in mind the question, (i.e what MIGHT be observed, from within the Bulk of events happening in our local brane,) Are you saying that no type of explosion in the brane would in any way be detectable in higher dimensions because they do not have a gravitational component?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Yeah sure, if there is other stuff floating around near the brane. It sounds more like dark matter than energy though.

Comment: @Bain "And also, couldn't quantum level events not leave behind a mark in the Bulk?" They certainly can if you want them to.

Comment: @Bain, Any time you have explosion, you're moving mass around. If gravity propagates braneward, then you can detect it through the redistribution of mass. You can't see the light because none of it goes braneward (the same way you can't see lasers in a vacuum unless they're pointed at you), but you could see the explosion the same way we see dark matter.

Comment: @Bain "So the scenario in my story is that some large energy event happens in the real world, but there is a higher-dimensional being that is alerted to that event...." I would go with something black-holey then. Something with a lot of gravity.

Comment: That supernova analogy is all fun and games until you crouch to get level with the table surface and get blinded.

Comment: The weak-gravity hypothesis, as far as I know, requires that we would see gravity obeying something like a inverse cube/quartic/etc law, rather than an inverse square law. The fact that no such observation has yet been made means that if such a "dimensional leak" exists, the extra dimensions are smaller than the distances at which we've tested gravity.

Comment: @chepner I would expect so too. But string theory is weird and I don't know the maths. For example we can imagine the "gravitational waves" decay quartically in directions outside the brane. But the waves that start in the brane remain in the brane and so decay squarely.

Comment: @chepner "The fact that no such observation has yet been made means. . . " There is no evidence for any of this brane and bulk mumbo-jumbo to begin with. My answer relies on pop-science lore.

Answer (score 2):

### Frame challenge: don't rely on higher dimensionality for this

I think you've maybe got an X-Y problem thing going on.

From comments, it appears your ultimate goal is this:

> the scenario in my story is that some large energy event happens in the real world, but there is a higher-dimensional being that is alerted to that event....and comes back to wreak revenge etc

You asked specifically about nuclear fission and supernovae. One problem is that nuclear fission is a common, naturally occurring event. So, if you arrange things such that nuclear fission is an extremely "loud" thing in higher dimensions, the result will be that the higher dimension is a deafening cacophony caused by the multitude of fission events that are not important to your story. Your higher-dimensional baddie will be hard-pressed to recognize the one event that your story cares about.

Supernovae are also naturally occurring, although they are far less frequent. The problem with making these "louder" is that they would be absurdly loud. In the real world, a supernovae briefly emits more light than an entire galaxy. If you try to make all energy events naturally more visible in higher dimensions, each supernova will blot out everything, like white-out conditions in a blizzard, each time there's a supernova *anywhere* within detection range.

Even more importantly, it makes no sense for a higher-dimensional being to seek revenge on people for a supernova. Consider:

> If a supernova explosion were to occur within about 25 light-years of Earth, our planet would probably lose its atmosphere, and all life would perish.
> -- supernova.eso.org

It would be absurd to blame creatures 25 light-years away for causing something bad. It would be even more absurd to posit that the higher-dimensional being would even notice us within a spherical volume 50 light-years in diameter. That would be like finding a dead body in your apartment and blaming people in a submarine on the far side of the planet for the murder.

---

This really seems like something it would be *better* to hand-wave. My advice is to simply assert that the high-energy event drew the attention of the higher-dimensional being. Don't try to explain that this was possible because high-energy events are "more noticeable" from a higher dimension. A creature from a higher dimension is scarier precisely *because* its higher-dimensional nature is not understood, and suggests that it might have all kinds of senses and powers that we can't even begin to speculate about. Don't ruin that by trying to explain to death the actual mechanism.

The other reason to not make this chain of events driven by higher-dimensionality *per se* is that it makes the high-energy event *less plausible* as a motivation for revenge. Revenge makes sense when something dear to the creature is threatened or harmed. Well, if there's something in this situation that's dear to the creature, it makes sense to suppose that the creature has taken precautions to ensure that it's safe. Consider: cattle are dear to ranchers, and wolves like to eat cows, so ranchers don't just leave their cattle all over the countryside -- they escort them from place to place, keep them behind fences, etc.

So, it'll probably make for a stronger revenge motivation if you tell a story where the higher-dimension being is constantly monitoring space for high-energy events, (as opposed to just them all just being "louder" because it's a higher dimension) because it understands that high-energy events pose an important threat. Thus, the creature notices the high-energy event because it is always looking for them, *not* because high-energy events are naturally louder in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

**It's kind of like an optical fiber.**

Sure, the energy from the supernova travels along our brane, but in the higher dimensional brane, the same photons carry light, they are just no longer restricted to a lower dimensional brane. If a sensor in the higher brane happens to pass through our brane, it could detect the event, just like you can see light passed through an optical fiber if you look at one end, even though you can't if you look at it from the side.

This assumes that there are some shared particles between our brane and the higher brane, but if, as OP said in a comment, the higher dimensional being wants to enact revenge, there probably should be some kind of shared particle to facilitate this interaction.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the nature of the observer.**

As inhabitants of a brane, we too are in the bulk.  All branes are in the bulk.   We have senses adapted for a 3 dimensional plane.  We cannot perceive events in other 3 dimensional planes noncontiguous with our own.

An "observer in the Bulk" might be in our brane, or might not, or might be in multiple branes.   The observer might not be a 3d creature like ourselves.  A higher dimensional creature might exist across multiple 3d planes and be able to perceive events in all of them.

Comment: For example, Ted Striker is a 3-D creature that existed across multiple planes, and the events he perceived in one such plane were so traumatic that he was almost unable to save another plane containing the woman he loved.